# Removing colour after drawing from Fabric JS leaves jagged edges

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, png, fabricjs, antialiasing

I need to remove a specific colour after drawing is done on a Fabric JS canvas and then export result as a png to an API. So, I am pasting the data onto another normal HTML5 canvas and using the following function:

```
removeColour: (context, color, width, height) ->
        ctx = context
        widthInt = parseInt(width, 10)
        heightInt = parseInt(height, 10)
        canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, widthInt, heightInt)
        pix = canvasData.data
        i = 0
        n = pix.length
        while i < n
            if @isApprox(pix[i], color[0], 60) and @isApprox(pix[i + 1], color[1], 60) and @isApprox(pix[i + 2], color[2], 60)
                pix[i + 3] = 0  # Setting alpha to zero i.e. making it transparent
            i += 4
        ctx.putImageData canvasData, 0, 0
        return
```

@isApprox() is just a method to allow nearby shades to be removed as well otherwise they remain along the edges.

I understand that these nearby colours are added by canvas to smoothen the edges, however after removing my exported image is left with horrible jagged lines as is visible in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I think there must be an alternative since the other edges e.g. outside curves in the shape are not jagged. Only the places from where the colour was removed and replaced with transparency, this is happening. (parts from where the background is visible.)

The source drawing on the canvas from which this is exported is the following:

[image: source screenshot]

Please note that in the source drawing the parts of the colour to be removed ([232,232,232] or #E8E8E8) are perfectly smooth and have no jagged lines.

I have read almost all anti-aliasing threads here and tried changing `globalCompositeOperation` also but that seems to have no effect.

Is there a way to get rid of the jagged edges ? For drawing, I am using simple pencil brush in Fabric JS. Even if the brush moves like a rectangular shape and does not produce curves, it will be fine.